# How to server js.gz pre compressed build angular app to IIS window 10

Tags: angular, iis

I have angular 10 application which is build for production with the following command using gzipper npm package.
"build:prod": "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer && gzipper compress --verbose ./dist./dist/gzipped"

now i have pre-compressed gz extentions files in my folder and trying to deploy it on my local IIS.

Files after Build and compressed.
[image: Pre-Compressed angular app]

I have tried no of solutions but no success. can any one please guide me how to achieve this or deploy over IIS.

I am getting this error

My Web config is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url="(.*).js" />
          <conditions></conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.js.gz" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Rewrite content-encoding header" preCondition="IsGZ" stopProcessing="false">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_CONTENT_ENCODING" pattern=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="gzip" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
          <preCondition name="IsGZ">
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.gz$" />
          </preCondition>


        </preConditions>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What is your error message and what did you try?

Comment: I am getting HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.